# VIDLE - Py 2.7 after saving as .py, no longer runs

Tags: vpython

I have been learning python for physics, 
im using VIDLE - Py 2.7,
I open a new file and without saving enter this code:

from visual import *

```
scene.width = 800
scene.height = 600
scene.autoscale = 0
scene.range = (100, 100, 100)
scene.center = (0, 40, 0)
#scene.fullscreen = 1

ball = sphere(pos=(0,103,1),radius = 2)


ground = box(pos=(0,-1,0),size=(100,2,100))
building = box(size = (6,100,6),pos=(0,50,0),color=color.blue)

gravity = 9.8 # m/s**2
velocityX = 7 #m/s
seconds = 0
dt = 0.05

finished = False
while not finished:
    rate(100)   # dont run through loop more than 100 times/sec
    seconds += dt

#position equation; y(t) = y0 + v0*t + .5 * a * t**2

ballY = 100 - .5 * gravity * seconds**2
ballX = velocityX * seconds


ball.pos = vector(ballX, ballY, 0)

if ballY -2 <=0:
    finished = True
    print "seconds to drop: " + str(seconds)
```

this successfully runs the program, but when i save it as a .py and then try to run it again in the same way I get an error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bencallaghan/Desktop/psyre.py", line 1
    from visual import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/VPython-6.05-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/visual/**init**.py", line 34
    from visual_common.create_display import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/VPython-6.05-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/visual_common/create_display.py", line 10
    import wx as _wx
  File "/usr/local/lib/wxPython-2.9.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.9.4-osx_cocoa/wx/**init**.py", line 45
    from wx._core import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/wxPython-2.9.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.9.4-osx_cocoa/wx/_core.py", line 5
    import new
  File "/Users/bencallaghan/Desktop/new.py", line 8
    from pylab import scatter,xlabel,ylabel,xlim,ylim,show
ImportError: No module named pylab

> > > 

My guess is that its running in some type of shell within Vpython that has access to visual and pylab but when I save it then tries to access them from somewhere else and it can't.
But beyond that reasoning I have little idea where to go from there
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you need to import pylab in the same way that you imported vpython at the first line.

```
from pylab import*
```

Also, it seems you will need to indent this way so that your position/velocity updates are contained within your while loop.  Hope this helps

```
while not finished:
    rate(100)   # dont run through loop more than 100 times/sec
    seconds += dt

    #position equation; y(t) = y0 + v0*t + .5 * a * t**2

    ballY = 100 - .5 * gravity * seconds**2
    ballX = velocityX * seconds


    ball.pos = vector(ballX, ballY, 0)

    if ballY -2 <=0:
        finished = True
        print "seconds to drop: " + str(seconds)
```

PS Not sure if the space between "import" and "*" is causing problems on your first line as well, should be:

```
from visual import*
```

not:

```
from visual import *
```

but this may be ok